# explain the syntax EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

Tags: java, android

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

in the line

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

`EditText` is class and 
`editText` is the instance we are creating.
`findViewById(R.id.edit_message)` is method and `R.id.edit_message` is the argument we are passing

But I can not understand why there is thos `(EditText)` present?
is it the call to constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's explicit typecasting. `findViewById()` returns a `View` and the `(EditText)` explicitly typecasts it to an `EditText` (which is a subclass of `View`). This works since the object returned in fact is-a `EditText`, that is, an object of that class or one of its subclasses. If it wasn't, you would get `ClassCastException`.

Read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

```
is it the call to constructor?
```

No.

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

in the above line `(EditText)` is for typecasting..

`findViewById()` which returns the `View` object.so we typecast it to `EditText` Object.

`EditText` is a sub class of `View` Class.

Answer (score 2):

In the following line...

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

`findViewById(R.id.edit_message)` returning a view...But this view is generalized concept, it can be any type of view. So you can't determine from this returned view that which type of is this. That's why you have to `Cast` that returned view to a specific view. Here, the returned view is casting down to `EditText` using `(EditText)`.

Comment: Yeah.. actually until now I did not had the privileged to upvote; being a newbie to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById(R.id.edit_message)` returns class `View`. `EditText` extends from this class, that's why we need to cast `View` to `EditText`.
If we need View class then we can simply write `View v = findViewById(R.id.some_view);`

Answer (score -1):

`<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>`